# Bijective Function from n-fold Cartesian Product to set of functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This is my first posting, so I apologize for the cumbersome formatting; I am not yet familiar with MathJax/Latex commands.

Let $Y$ be a set and let $n$ be an element of $\mathbb N$ (natural numbers). Define $Y^{n} = Y \times Y \times \dots \times Y$ (where $Y$ appears $n$ times), the $n$-fold cartesian product of $Y$ with itself. Then
$$
Y^{n} = \{(x_{1}, x_{2},\ldots, x_{n})\mid x_{i} \in Y\enspace \forall 1 \le i \le n\}.
$$

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Let $Fun(X,Y)$ denote the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$, that is, $f \in Fun(X,Y)$ if and only if $f\colon X \to Y$ is a function. Prove that there exists a function
$$
B\colon Y^{n} \to Fun(N_{n},Y)
$$
that is a bijection by defining the function $B$ appropriately and proving that $B$ is an injection and a surjection.

I know the definitions of injection and surjection, and feel fairly confident that I could prove a function that is just concerning two sets, say $A$ and $B$, to be one, the other, or both, but I am struggling with the notation and all of the extra criteria. Any tips or guidance for how to get this proof started would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $N_n$?.

Comment: This is probably my error. The N is supposed to be \mathbb N_n. For some reason, this won't display correctly (input error?).

Comment: Ok, what is $\mathbb N_n$? It's $n$ itself? But it must be a set.

Comment: Yes, it is a set, which makes sense. I'm not sure what the subscript is supposed to denote, however, or how to go about relating $Y^{n}$ to Fun($N_{n}$,Y).